# Skip to a Page on Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm programatically creating a Google Form using Google App Scripts right now, and my script automatically generates a page for each of the respondants that the form will be emailed out to.

Currently, the form has a dropdown at the beginning that the person uses to select their page, and then it forwards them to it, however, I'd prefer it if the email already sent out a pre-responded form that already started them on their page.

The reason I'm throwing them all into a single form is because I'm using Triggers to detect the form's submission, and since I have more than 20 people that require a form, that would break the trigger limit.

EDIT:
Example code:
the `Form.getPublishedUrl()` function returns the URL to respond the form, starting on the first page, however, I would like a URL to respond to the form starting on the 3rd or 4th page.

While the `FormResponse.toPrefilledUrl()` will allow me to autofill the correct response on the first page, it will not allow me to start the responder on the page that he would be forwarded to based on his pre-filled response on the first page.

**tldr; :**

How do I get a link to a specific page on a Google Form using Google App Scripts?

Comment: Please post some code. What do you mean by link to a specific page?

Comment: Further explanation posted.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but don't have 50 rep yet...

Why do you need various HTML pages?
I think you should refactor your code so every form is on the same HTML and everything shows and hides with Jquery or Javascript. You can send the same URL but with differente URL parameters.

If this isn't your case, you should post some code of yours and detail a little bit more your question. Also, wich limit does it triggers?

Comment: I'm using Google Forms(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/), not an HTML page.

Google has a 20 trigger limit per script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Oops, my bad, missread, but what your asking can be easily done with the method I mentioned in the answer, it's pretty easy to make a form using GAS. See here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/ and here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication. Plus, you can make it look like whatenever you want with HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Comment: As for doing in forms, you can manipulate Properties wich can be read cross scripts, but only in the same user, or cross users in the same script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/.